# Unable to use inject from angular mocks

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

I am working on an AngularJS app. One of my services is really buggy. For that reason, I want to test it. To run those tests, I wanted to use a grunt task. The idea is, I would type `grunt test` from the command line to run my unit tests. My first step was creating my grunt file, which looks like this:

**gruntfile.js**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    jasmine: {
      mocks: {
        src: 'dist/service.min.js',
        options: {
          specs: 'test/*.js',
          vendor: [
            'bower_components/angularjs/angular.min.js',
            'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js'
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  });

  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
  grunt.registerTask('test', ['jasmine:unitTests']);
};
```

Then, my tests would look like this:

**service.spec.js**

```
describe('myModule', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    module('myModule');
  });

  describe('$myService', function () {
    var service = null;
    beforeEach(inject(function ($myService) {
      service = $myService;
    }));

    it('should get here', function () {
      console.log('first test');
      var isSynchronized = service.isSynchronized();
      expect(isSynchronized).toBe(true);
    });
  });
})
```

This test is intended to test my service:

**service.js**

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myModule', [])
    .factory('$myService', [function () {    
        return {    
            isSynchronized: function () {
                return true;
            }
        };
    }]
);
```

My problem has to do with the `inject` command in the tests. That function call causes the test to break. If I remove the beforeEach block that uses inject, the test at least runs. I keep hearing about Karma. However, I don't know much about it.

Is Karma a required piece to test AngularJS services? I can't find an example of testing an ngularJS service from grunt. Everything I see is in the browser. I'm trying to create the minimum required grunt file that will allow me to test my AngularJS service. However, I'm totally stuck. I can't figure out why inject is failing.

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing. Or, perhaps point me to an example that uses grunt to test an AngularJS service? Currently, I see the following in the command line, so I know service.js exists.

```
Running "uglify:mocks" (uglify) task
Verifying property uglify.mocks exists in config...OK
Files: dist/service.js -> dist/service.min.js
Options: banner="", footer="", compress, mangle={}, beautify=false, report="min", expression=false, preserveComments=false
Minifying with UglifyJS...Reading dist/service.js...OK
OK
Writing dist/service.min.js...OK
File dist/service.min.js created: 293 B → 190 B

Running "jasmine:mocks" (jasmine) task
Verifying property jasmine.mocks exists in config...OK
Files: dist/service.min.js
Options: version="2.0.1", timeout=10000, styles=[], specs="test/*.js", helpers=[], vendor=["bower_components/angularjs/angular.min.js","bower_components/angular
-mocks/angular-mocks.js"], outfile="_SpecRunner.html", host="", template="C:\\source\\myModule\\node_modules\\grunt-contrib-jasmine\\tasks/jasmine
/templates/DefaultRunner.tmpl", templateOptions={}, junit={}, ignoreEmpty=false, display="full", summary=false
Reading C:\source\myModule\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jasmine\tasks\lib/../jasmine/reporters/PhantomReporter.js...OK
Writing .grunt\grunt-contrib-jasmine\reporter.js...OK
Reading C:\source\myModule\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jasmine\tasks\lib/../../vendor/jasmine-2.0.1/jasmine.css...OK
Writing .grunt\grunt-contrib-jasmine\jasmine.css...OK
Reading C:\source\myModule\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jasmine\tasks\lib/../../vendor/jasmine-2.0.1/jasmine.js...OK
Writing .grunt\grunt-contrib-jasmine\jasmine.js...OK
Reading C:\source\myModule\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jasmine\tasks\lib/../../vendor/jasmine-2.0.1/jasmine-html.js...OK
Writing .grunt\grunt-contrib-jasmine\jasmine-html.js...OK
Reading C:\source\myModule\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jasmine\tasks\lib/../../vendor/jasmine-2.0.1/boot.js...OK
Writing .grunt\grunt-contrib-jasmine\boot.js...OK
Reading C:\source\myModule\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jasmine\tasks\lib/../../vendor/jasmine-2.0.1/jasmine_favicon.png...OK
Writing .grunt\grunt-contrib-jasmine\jasmine_favicon.png...OK
Reading C:\source\myModule\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jasmine\tasks\lib/../../node_modules/es5-shim/es5-shim.js...OK
Writing .grunt\grunt-contrib-jasmine\es5-shim.js...OK
Reading C:\source\myModule\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jasmine\tasks/jasmine/templates/DefaultRunner.tmpl...OK
Processing source...OK
Writing _SpecRunner.html...OK

Testing jasmine specs via phantom
```

Thank you!

Comment: What's the error message you're getting? You don't need to use Karma. grunt-contrib-jasmine should work too.

Comment: The src parameter to grunt-contrib-jasmine should be a pattern that matches all the files your testing. Is `service.js` in `'dist/ngCordovaMocks.min.js'`

Comment: @rob - I renamed the src value to the correct one. It is still not working. I'm getting this error: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod?p0=myModule. I've confirmed that dist/service.min.js exists. Is the working directory getting changed somehow? I don't understand why its not loading my file. How can I be sure my file is getting loaded? When I run grunt --verbose, I get the following:

Comment: @rob - I added the output in the original post due to its size. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I still don't see the error message you're getting. What happens if you open up _SpecRunner.html in a browser? If you look at the source for _SpecRunner.html is it including all of your test files in script tags?

Comment: I don't see _SpecRunner.html anywhere. My devDependencies look like this:   "devDependencies": {
    "grunt-contrib-clean":"0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jasmine": "0.7.0",    
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "0.9.2",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify":"0.5.1",
    "load-grunt-tasks":"0.6.0"
  },